# In fish, how do you bind a command to `<ctrl>-,`?

Tags: bind, fish

I tried both `bind '\c,' 'echo hello ; commandline -f repaint'`  and `bind \c\, 'echo hello ; commandline -f repaint'` but it doesn't seem to make the expected effect.

Is this even mappable?

Comment: Historically, that is with hardware terminals like the DEC VT100, the control key simply modified the value sent by the other key to just the low five bits. That is, it did the equivalent of `key & 0x1F`. Modern software terminals provide more flexibility but even they don't send a distinct sequence for every control key combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this even mappable?

It is probably not.

If you wish to know what sequence to write for a given key chord, start `fish_key_reader` and press it.

In my terminal, pressing ctrl-, sends just ",". Which means it's indistinguishable from just a comma.